# Monitor not shown - is it a monitor or card issue?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a Windows-7-64 PC with onboard graphics plus an NVIDIA GeForce 8500 GT card. The onboard (Intel HD graphics 4000) graphics has been driving one (1920x1200) monitor via its VGA output, while the GeForce card has been driving a (2560x1600) monitor via its DVI cable. All was working fine when I last switched off my machine - but upon switching it back on again the graphics is only appearing via the onboard VGA.

I am confused as to whether my problem is my monitor or my card.

If I attempt to run the "NVIDIA control panel" software, I immediately get a dialog saying "NVIDIA Display settings are not available. You are not currently using a display attached to an NVIDIA GPU." Then "close" is the only button available to click. But if I go to device manager and click "display adaptors", it shows both cards. Furthermore, if I click the NVIDIA card text, I see a properties dialog claiming "This device is working properly".

Comment: When you open the "screen Resolution" option from a right click on the desktop, do you see both your monitors there ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a fix but it could be.  Go get the latest drivers for your video card in case you haven't.  From there, if you're on a laptop check for function key buttons to toggle displays.  Windows also can do the same thing by right clicking your desktop -> screen resolution -> click the monitor that isn't working and set it how you want it.  (multiple displays -> extend these displays)